# Multiple IP's on the same bridge

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, bridge

I'm setting up a Ubuntu host machine for a couple of kvm virtual machines. Here is my interface config file:

```
# config block 0
auto lo vmbr0
iface lo inet loopback
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 111.111.111.111
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 111.111.111.1
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off



# config block 1
auto he-ipv6
iface he-ipv6 inet6 v4tunnel
        address 2001:470:1f06:639::2
        netmask 64
        endpoint 209.51.161.14
        local 111.111.111.111
        ttl 255
        gateway 2001:470:1f06:639::1



# config block 2
iface vmbr0 inet6 static
        address 2001:470:1f07:639::
        netmask 64
        gateway 2001:470:1f06:639::2



# config block 3
iface vmbr0 inet6 static
        address 2001:470:8a2a:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
        netmask 64
        gateway 2001:470:1f06:639::2
```

Let's say `config block 0` is the bridge `vmbr0` to `eth0`. `config block 1` is the WAN IPv6 interface. `config block 2` is my routable /64, and `config block 3` is my routable /48. Now I found if the `config block 2` and `config block 3` both exist in the config file, only the IP in `config block 2` works, and if I remove one of `config block 2` or `config block 3`, the one left will work. So it seems I cannot config more than one additional IP addresses on the same bridge?

Comment: Did you try the old-style alias configuration style? (i.e. changing block 3 to `face vmbr0:0 inet6 static`)

Comment: Thanks @SanderSteffann. I just tried, change block 3 to `face vmbr0:0 inet6 static` still doesn't work.